# Feat apply order (one increased radiant damage, other changes damage type)

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, damage-types

If one feat increases radiant damage (e.g. Superior Implement Training and using a Astral Implement which increases radiant damage by 2) and another feat converts the damage type of a power from radiant to cold damge (e.g. Power of Winter converting Hand of Radiance's damage to cold), will the first bonus still apply, because it was applied **before** changing the damage type?

Is this depending on the feat order (Level 1 feat is applied before level 2 feat and so on)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You would not get that damage bonus in this case.

From Divine Power, p123 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Power of Winter**
> ...
> When you use a power associated with this feat, the power's damage changes to cold (the power gains the cold keyword and *loses the keywords of its former damage types*). ...

So when you use Hand of Radiance, it loses the *Radiant* keyword and gains the *Cold* keyword instead.

From PHB3, p195 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Energized:** When you use an attack power through an energized implement, you gain a +2 bonus to *damage rolls* if the power *has the keyword that matches the implement's damage type*. ...

So when you use the the astral implement with an power that has the *Radiant* keyword, it deals bonus damage on damage rolls.

You don't gain the bonus damage from your Energized (radiant) superior implement on Hand of Radiance because it never had the *Radiant* keyword. Power of Winter replaces the *Radiant* keyword with the *Cold* keyword any time you use Hand of Radiance, so Hand of Radiance doesn't qualify for Energized when you roll its damage.